# In Unity, Change which mouse button is used to scroll in ScrollRect

Tags: unity, mouse, ui-design, scrolling

I've created a new ScrollView in Unity. How do I change which mouse button is used to scroll in ScrollRect (through script or in the editor).

By default it's the left mouse button. I'd like to be able to change this to another mouse button.

I'd also like to be able to use a keyboard key and disable it altogether (via script without also disabling the scrollbars), but mainly I at least want to change it from the left mouse button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the UI source from bitbucket. Default input should be changed by changing those left mouse button input.[image: Unity UI source]

Or you may override those methods.

Comment: Thanks.  Here's a simple code example if anyone stumbles upon this and needs one: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1203095/change-which-mouse-button-is-used-to-scroll-in-scr.html